# Did anyone involved in Star Wars other than George Lucas think it was a good idea to make Greedo shoot first?

Tags: a-new-hope, behind-the-scenes, star-wars

The articles I've read about the whole "Han shot first" controversy always present it as George Lucas unilaterally changing something that wasn't broken and all of the fans getting upset about it because it didn't really improve the movie (to put it mildly). But it occurred to me the other day that I've never seen anyone explicitly claim that Lucas made this decision without consulting anyone else's opinion, or that literally no one else supported him on it, so now I'm curious whether that implication is accurate.

I'm specifically asking for **people involved in the creation of Star Wars movies**, of any trilogy, who publicly expressed a positive opinion about the "Greedo shot first" change in the 1997 Special Edition of Episode IV. Ideally someone who was involved in the special edition itself.

Comment: So you're asking if George shot (it) first?

Comment: I would *presume* that any such person would have been in the employ of Mr Lucas at the time. If your boss asks you what you think of his "exciting" new idea , what do you say?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I read in an interview with the developers of the canceled Star Wars game *1313* that one of the higher ups (head of LucasArts maybe?) would coach developers on what to say before meeting with George Lucas, in particular telling them to not argue against his ideas. It's not clear whose idea it was (could easily have been the higher ups' and not Lucas'), but it does seem that there was a company culture of following whatever George said no matter what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only person I can find to have commented either way (beyond Lucas himself) was Paul Blake, the actor who played Greedo. [He said](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/greedo-actor-star-wars-restore-han-solo-shooting-article-1.2623730)

> "Of course, in it said it all in the original script, we played in the scene in English and at the end of the scene, it reads, 'Han shoots the alien.' " Blake told the Daily News. "It's all it says and that's what happened. It was very painful."
>
> Besides, having Greedo fire first and miss from across a table, as has been the case after the original release, is sort of embarrassing.
>
> "He was a bit inept wasn't he?" quips Blake. "He's a worse shot than a Stormtrooper. I don't think Jabba had him under a pension plan let's put it that way.
>
> "It would be lovely to see them go back to the original version, I much preferred it, I must say. And it does give it Greedo a little more glory if he's just blown away."

It's important to remember that George Lucas insists that was how the scene was always supposed to go, but none of the scripts support that assertion. What's weird is that there exist no quotes supporting this. I'd at least expect someone to "yes-man" this by now, but nobody has. That the only comment comes from someone with a tertiary role (poor guy gets a whopping minute of screen time) says that it's likely that people will keep that silence, rather than anger fans or Lucas.

[Harrison Ford's official comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/22xh4j/i_am_harrison_harrison_ford_ama/cgrbxl4)

> I don't know and I don't care.